# Query for the existance of a Process (flow)

Tags: apex, process

In some orgs I work in, there is a process setup that automates creating some objects after an object is created.  This process does not exist in all orgs.  I've written Apex code that imports data from a CSV file.  I'd like to add code to my import routine that checks to see if the process exists.  If it does not, I can add code to my import routine that replicates what the process is doing.  Is there a way within Apex to query for the existence of a process by its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cheat you may be able to use is to ask for it by name:

```
Boolean flowExists = false;
try {
  new PageReference('/flow/MyFlowName').getContent();
  flowExists = true;
} catch(VisualforceException e) {
}
```

This will work wherever callouts/getContent is allowed, so I'm not sure if that helps you in your specific use case, but it might be worth looking at.

---

You can also try to invoke the flow directly:

```
Boolean flowExists = false;
try {
    Flow.Interview.createInterview('FlowName', new Map<String, Object>());
    flowExists = true;
} catch(TypeException e) {

}
```

Comment: I tried your second solution, and it worked great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need to call out to the `Tooling API` and retrieve [`FlowDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowdefinition.htm) records.

You can start playing around with an anonymous script like below to get a feel for what you actually need to build:

```
String auth = 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId();
String query = 'SELECT DeveloperName, ActiveVersionId FROM FlowDefinition';
String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
    '/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=' +
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', auth);
request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
system.debug(response.getBody());
```

Comment: That definitely works.  However, when I clone a Trialforce org, it doesn't have the remote site settings in it that would allow this to work without user intervention.  I'm thinking if there is a way to create those remote site settings when the org is cloned...

Comment: I think you got a bit literal with the word "query" in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to query flows/processes via this SOAP API object - [FlowDefinitionView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_flowdefinitionview.htm?search_text=flow)

```
List<FlowDefinitionView> flows = [
   SELECT ApiName, DurableId, TriggerType, Label 
   FROM FlowDefinitionView 
   WHERE IsActive=true AND ApiName='MyFlow'
];
Boolean isFlowActive = !flows.isEmpty();
```